# JS Call new Class().function1().function2() and keep "this"

Tags: javascript, class

I have a problem with Class Javascript.
I created class with constructor and two functions.

```
export default class Example {
  private image: string;
  private processedImage: Sharp | undefined;

  constructor(image: string) {
    this.image = image;
  }

  resize(): ResizeClb {
    this.processedImage = resizeImage(this.image, ...);

    return {
      merge: this.merge
    };
  }

  merge(images: MergeImages[]): void {
    console.log(this.processedImage); // print undefined 
    this.processedImage = this.processedImage.composite(layers);
  }
}
```

I want call chained functions:

```
const a = new Example(myImage).resize().merge(...othersImages);
```

But when I called the chained function I get undefined in this.processedImage line.
I can't access to value of the class.

It's work if I not use chains functions.

```
const a = new Example(myImage);
a.resize();
a.merge(...othersImages); // It work.
```

It work but I required use chains functions.
Thank you!

Comment: Make the merge method a class field arrow function instead

Comment: why not just `return this;`